# NameError in signals pre_save

Tags: python, django, signals, sender

when i try to make a slugfield , and when i write the pre_save code it doesn't reconize my model i don't know why , please help

this is my model :

```
from django.db import models
from post.utils import unique_slug_generator
from django.db.models import signals
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
class product(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    price=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    discription=models.TextField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def slug_save(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
        if not instance.slug:
            instance.slug=unique_slug_generator(instance,instance.title,instance.slug)

    pre_save.connect(slug_save, sender =product)
```

utils.py:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify


def unique_slug_generator(model_instance,title,slug_field):
    slug=slugify(title)
    model_class=model_istance.__clas__
    while model_class._default_manager.filter(slug=slug).exists():
        object_pk=model_class._default_manager.latest(pk)
        object_pk=object_pk.pk + 1
        slug=f'{slug}-{object_pk}'
        return slug
```

the error message :

```
class product(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Madara\Desktop\khkh\sluger\post\models.py", line 28, in product
    pre_save.connect(slug_save, sender =product)
NameError: name 'product' is not defined
```

Comment: Move both the `slug_save` method and the line connecting the signal outside of your class definition. You cannot reference a class inside it's definition as it has not yet been created

Comment: the line `pre_save.connect(slug_save, sender =product)` should be a part of the model class.